# Allow eval() to evaluate only arithmetic expressions and certain functions

Tags: python, eval

I have a calculator that uses the `eval()` function to evaluate expressions, but I am aware of the fact that using `eval()` is dangerous as it can be used to run arbitrary code on the machine.

So, I want it to only be able to evaluate arithmetic expressions and certain defined functions (imported from another file).

consolecalc.py:

```py
from mymathmodule import *
import time
while True:
    try:   
       Choose = '''Choose your function:
       1: Percentage calculator
       2: Factorial calculator
       3: Basic arithmetics (+-*/)
       '''
       for character in Choose:
        print(character, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.006)
       a = int(input(':'))
       if a == 1:
           percentagecalc()
       elif a == 2:
           factorialcalc()
       elif a == 3:
           calc = input("Enter Expression:")
           print("Expression equals:",eval(calc))
       else:
           print("\nOops! Error.  Try again...") 
       time.sleep(0.6)
    except:
       print("\nOops! Error.  Try again...")    
       time.sleep(0.6)
```

The defined functions are present in *mymathmodule.py* and I only want `eval()` to be able to evaluate those along with basic arithmetic expressions

I would also like to know if there are any alternatives to `eval()` that could do this for me...

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of regular `eval` since it's supposed to be safe according to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval with the worst that can happen is interpreter crashing.

Comment: @pavel doesn't that also disallow it to run the functions I defined and want it to run?

Comment: Yes. And it doesn't allow operators either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the global and local namespace to `eval()` as a dict. If the globals contain `__builtins__` none of the normal builtin functions can be called from the passed string. You can also use this to provide your own functions, e.g.

```py
globs = {
    "__builtins__": {},
    "sqrt": my_sqrt_fun
}
```

If you pass that to eval then `sqrt` in the input will call `my_sqrt_fun`

```py
eval("3 + sqrt(3)", globs, {})
```

When an assignment occurs within the expression using the walrus operator, it will be set in the local dictionary, hence the empty dictionary. You *could* use this allow variables to be set, but to prevent users from overwriting anything, use that dictionary only for that purpose.

Passing e.g. `exec` will raise a `NameError`, so no arbitrary code can be executed this way.

Comment: well, this seems to work for exec(), but for input:  https://imgur.com/cjVriIz

Comment: oh my bad on that one.. found an error in the code.. it does work. Thanks!

Comment: As the number of functions in _mymathmodule.py_ increased, I discovered that `eval(calc), {'__builtins__': None}, vars(mymathmodule))` is actually even better.
The vars() method calls all functions from mymathmodule to the local namespace, and only allows them to run, as `'__builtins__'` is still set to none

Comment: @SK-the-Learner Note that if you pass a local dictionary, users can use the walrus operator to set variables in that dictionary. If you would eval `"(x:=0)"` using that method, `mymathmodule.x` would be set.

Comment: @SK-the-Learner I just realized this problem with assignment also exists with no local dict. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Turns out ChatGPT isn't always bad 

        `locals_dict = vars(mymathmodule)
        globals_dict = {k: v for k, v in globals().items() if k not in locals_dict}
        globals_dict.pop('__builtins__', None)
        expression = eval(input("Enter Expression:"), globals_dict, locals_dict)
        print("Expression equals:",expression)`

is what it suggested to my code:
`expression = eval(input("Enter Expression:"),{'__builtins__': None}, vars(mymathmodule))
 print("Expression equals:",expression)`

seems pretty much working. ChatGPT big-brain moment lol

Comment: That still has the problem described above. In addition: because that removes `'__builtins__'` from the global dict, Python will provide _the default builtins_

Comment: Well.. my bad again. you are right.. this code allows for inbuilt functions..
How do you suggest should I make a dictionary that dynamically adds all variables/functions from mymathmodule to a dictionary so that I can implement the dictionary without worrying to update it everytime I make a new function in mymathmodule?

Comment: `globals_dict = { k: v for k,v in vars(mymathmodule) if not k.startswith('__') }; globals_dict['__builtins__'] = {}` That will keep all of the dundle variables out. Python adds a bunch off special entries to a module; harmless (except __builtins__) but this'll keep it clean. And for the locals, either pass a new empty dict each time, or keep one. If you keep one around, the user can set variables that he can reuse.

Comment: I was trying to implement your suggestion, but ran into issues with it (would throw an error). But finally ended up at `locals_dict = vars(mymathmodule)
        globals_dict = {k: v for k, v in globals().items() if k not in locals_dict}
        globals_dict['__builtins__'] = {}
        expression = eval(input("Enter Expression:"), globals_dict, locals_dict)`
and that seems to work. The walrus operator can still be used to create variables but does not call builtin functions: https://imgur.com/aFdgSK4